Using Outlook Interop : Could not load file or assembly 'office
In my winforms .NET Core project, i'd like to create a mail in Outlook.
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
mail.Subject = "Envoi du fichier 'strExportFileName" & "'"
mail.Body = ""
mail.[To] = ""
Dim attachmentPath As String = "strExportFilePath"
mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentPath, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
mail.Display(True)

If I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. i got this error on runtime:
Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
If I use the COM Reference, my code don't compile.
I found several similar questions here and there but i don't get how to resolve it.

Ok, i found a way to solve it.

Uninstall Nuget Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Add Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Objet library
Delete the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook from the Assemblies list

In the end, you must see "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" only in COM list, like this 
